# How can I sort users by date and time of logging in to a Ubuntu server

Tags: command-line

I set up a VM Ubuntu server for a project and then logged with different accounts in from multiple putty instances. I don't have a good grasp of the commands yet, I only know a few basics. I need to find specific usernames of users (`grep`?), also sorted by time of logging in. So if anyone could suggest a command most likely piped with `who`, it would be a great help.

Comment: Isn't the output of `who` sorted by login date/time by default? Please [edit] your question to describe more specifically what you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Steeldriver `who` or `last` do this and by default **sorts** their outputs by date and time. For the `grep` command you will have `pipe` the output of those two commands to `grep` with the `-i` (ignore case) and `-F`(Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings [instead of regular expressions], separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.) flags with the desired `username` in mind to get the output, example: `last | grep -iF george`.

Comment: Should also maybe use the `F` flag (or the `fgrep` command), so that, for example, usernames with dots don't cause regex-related problems.